# Is increase in current speeding up the electrons or is it just focusing velocities of electrons in the same direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, electric-current, conductors, speed

Current in a wire is defined as the amount of charge that passes through a cross-section of that wire in a single second. By this definition alone, it is clear that a current relies on the motion of some charged particle. I believe it is possible that electrons could transfer energy to each other in every direction and when the current starts flowing those energy transfers are more directional. This could lead to electrons always having the same velocity independently of the current. Is this the case?

I came up with this wile trying to understand magnetic force around wire, if electrons are traveling in the same direction their spins would also be in the same direction, which could cause magnetic field similarly that would spinning ball in viscose liquid cause flow of that liquid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Current in a wire is defined as the amount of charge that passes
> through a cross-section of that wire in a single second.

Basically correct.

> By this definition alone, it is clear that a current relies on the
> motion of some charged particle.

Better to say current is the collective motion of charged particles in a given direction, which is related to the their drift velocity.

> I believe it is possible that electrons could transfer energy to each
> other in every direction and when the current starts flowing those
> energy transfers are more directional.

Even without current, which is the result of an applied electric field, electrons are constantly in random thermal motion. When the field is applied, in addition to the thermal motion there is the collective motion (drift velocity) of the electrons.

> This could lead to electrons always having the same velocity
> independently of the current. Is this the case?

But those electron velocities are random motion. They have no effect on the current and the current has no effect on the random motion. As a rough analogy, consider a school of fish in the ocean randomly darting about but also collectively moving along the shore line due to ocean currents.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage increase means that the electrons are pushed / pulled through the conductor with more force. Current increase means that more electrons are moved per time unit.

Interesting is your consideration "if electrons are travelling in the same direction their spins would also be in the same direction, which could cause magnetic field". In fact, an electron has two fields, its electric dipole and its magnetic dipole. And indeed, one should consider that when a voltage is applied and a current flows, the valence band electrons - with the previously chaotic position of their magnetic dipoles - experience an alignment.